# JasperReports "Split type" property of Band

Tags: jasper-reports

I have two Elements `Table` and `Static Text`, for example.
Can i do with JasperReports next logic:

- When `Table` height more than report `Page` height then print `Static Text` on first page `Teble` on second page
- When `Table` height less than report `Page` height then first print `Table` second print `Static Text` at first page.

In common words, how i can force "prevent split" behaviour for only first element in `Band` and only first element in `Band` to move to next page if it needed and all other elements to move to top of `Band` where was first element?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
<reportElement x="0" y="0" width="80" height="40">
        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER} == 1]]></printWhenExpression>
</reportElement>
```